# Error: cannot find symbol downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

Tags: java

There is an error with the below line.

> cannot find symbol downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

```
private void StoringImageToFirebaseStorage() {
    Calendar calFordData = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    saveCurrentData = currentDate.format(calFordData.getTime());

    Calendar calFordTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calFordData.getTime());

    postRandomName = saveCurrentData + saveCurrentTime;

    StorageReference filePath = PostsImagesRefrence.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment()+ postRandomName + ".jpg");

    filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Image uploaded successfully to storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                SavingPostInformationToDatabase();
            }
            else{
                String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare downloadUrl as a string.

```
private void StoringImageToFirebaseStorage() {

        Calendar calFordData = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        saveCurrentData = currentDate.format(calFordData.getTime());

        Calendar calFordTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calFordData.getTime());

        postRandomName = saveCurrentData + saveCurrentTime;

        StorageReference filePath = PostsImagesRefrence.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment()+ postRandomName + ".jpg");

        filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Image uploaded successfully to storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    SavingPostInformationToDatabase();
                }
                else{
                    String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @N.keerthana Santhi do you are got resolved with my suggestion? If so would you mind accepting my answer and +1 to post?

Comment: Please tell me some other solutions.

Comment: @N.keerthanaSanthi are you declaring downloadUrl somewhere in class? I don't see the declaration of downloadUrl. Add complete code so I can help you.

Comment: @N.keerthanaSanthi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        downloadUrl =  uri.toString();
                        SavingPostInformationToDatabase();
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Image uploaded successfully to storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```